# Trace $\sigma$-algebra is $\sigma$-algebra: What's wrong with my counterexample?

Tags: measure-theory

Trace $\sigma$-algebra is $\sigma$-algebra (Schilling, 2005, p. 16):

[image]

My proposed counterexample:

> Let $X=\{ 1,2,3\} $. Then $\mathcal{A}=\{ \varnothing,X\} $ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$.
>
> Let $E=\{1\}$. Then $\mathcal{A}_E=\{\varnothing, \{1\}\}$ but is not a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$.

What mistake(s) have I made above?

Comment: You've misread the definition, it seems. It's claim is that it is a $\sigma$-algebra of $E$, not of $X$.

Comment: @Hayden: Ah OK! Yes got it thanks!